# Can cultist be missed?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I've killed 4 of the 5 cultists and the sage on the Worshippers of the Bloodline branch of the cult. The last cultist in the branch is still an "Undiscovered Cultist" (shown as a cult mask), with the hint

> Hunt other Cultists from the same branch to gain a Clue about this Cultist's identity.

There are no other Cultists in the branch left to hunt (sage included). Did I miss the Clue that unlocks this cultist? Can I go back and find it somewhere?

The cultist I'm missing is the far right end of the lower branch of the Worshippers of the Bloodline. On that branch I've killed

> Zoisme, Harpalos, Diona, Melite, and the sage Iokaste

Comment: Asking here rather than googling the last cultist so I can avoid spoilers. If your answer includes spoilers, please tag/warn appropriately. Just trying to figure out if I need to just keep playing to find out or if I screwed something up

Comment: did you update your game to the latest version?

Comment: @BlackCrystal I let it update whenever it says there is an update. I think the most recent big update it downloaded was a week or two ago. Can I force it to check for newer updates?

Comment: i had the same problem and i updated my game and it was fixed. maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: @BlackCrystal I've confirmed everything is up to date to the lastest. Didn't fix the issue

Comment: did you go to the Epidauros Sanctuary? the hunt starts from there.

Comment: or the city that bloody oracle is. you can find the cultist there. try to play side quest in the city and sanctuary.

Comment: @BlackCrystal that is actually the part of the story I am playing today, and the cultist has just been revealed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out "hunt other Cultists" was misleading/incorrect. This cultist is discovered by playing through the main story line, not hunting the other Cultists in the branch.

> While searching for the mother, completing the quest Priests of Asklepios will reveal Chrysis, the last cultist in this branch